# Bounding $\prod_{p<x}\frac{p^2}{p^2-1}$ by a constant where p is a prime with $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$

Tags: number-theory

Please can someone help find a constant bound for this it seems to tend to infinity

Comment: What part? I’m not sure what you mean

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: take (natural) logarithm, use, for $t > 0,$  $\; \log (1+t) < t \; \; .$

Comment: @Wojowu I tried to bound it with a product of $e^{\frac{1}{p^2}}$ and then do the infinite sum but it didn’t work

Comment: @WillJagy please could you be a little more specific I’m still confused thanks

Comment: $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac {\pi^2}{6} \; \; \; . \; \; \;$ $\sum  \frac{1}{p^2} < \frac {\pi^2}{6} \; \; \; . \; \; \;$  $\sum  \frac{1}{p^2 - 1} < \frac {\pi^2}{6} \; \; \; . \; \; \;$

Comment: @WillJagy but how do you go from the product to the sum

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product#Examples

Comment: @Winther thank you that’s just what i needed but is there a simple way to prove that Euler product for $s=2$ because I haven’t found that in lectures

Answer (score 1):

$$
\prod\limits_{\substack{p < x \\ p \equiv 3\bmod 4}} {\frac{{p^2 }}{{p^2  - 1}}}  < \prod\limits_{p < x} {\frac{{p^2 }}{{p^2  - 1}}}  < \prod\limits_p {\frac{{p^2 }}{{p^2  - 1}}}  = \prod\limits_p {\frac{1}{{1 - \frac{1}{{p^2 }}}}}  = \zeta (2) = \frac{{\pi ^2 }}{6} <  + \infty .
$$

Comment: I began with the last product and worked the other way thinking I was simplifying it because I don’t think Ive been taught the Riemann part